# PostgreSQL: What is data replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I read from a post about comparing MySQL and PostgreSQL, there is one who said:

> The biggest disadvantage of PG for me had been the lack of
>   replication, but it's recently gotten both asynchronous and
>   synchronous replication.

Source: https://www.quora.com/What-are-pros-and-cons-of-PostgreSQL-and-MySQL

So my question is: What does that "PostgreSQL lacks replication" mean?

Comment: The fact that the article says "recently" means it's badly outdated and pretty much ignorable. The first entry in that list is incredibly, blatantly wrong about MySQL too. Ignore it, it's garbage. I wish I could just make that whole article go away and get rid of some Wrong on the Internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means nothing, really. PostgreSQL has a number of replication features, as [the relevant chapter in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) details.

That article is apallingly wrong and outdated. Ignore it. "No referential integrity" in MySQL? Bah.

If you have an account on that site, please ask for it to be removed or fixed or whatever can be done. As it stands it's dangerously misleading and wrong, and has no place claiming to be current accurate information.

Comment: To be fair: the "no referential integrity" is the statement that is plain wrong on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to read that article.  Replication is the ability to create a copy of itself as you'll see for backup/disaster-recovery or for distributed systems, such as a CDN.

Synchronous vs Asynchronous is how that backup is performed.  Synchronous keeps all databases in sync.  Asynchronous queues updates, which means if the primary server goes down before data is transferred, you might have data loss.

There are a number of replication features, such as load balancing or connection pooling.  Postgres may not have them all, but it has a decent amount (there are 3rd party tools for what can't be satisfied by the native application).

There's a chance whatever you read was comparing older versions of both MySQL and PostgreSQL.  However, you can always see more information about Postgres features in its **[wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling)**.